# Connecting independent Excel File Upload and Parsing Code in Java - NewBee :)

Tags: java, excel, spring, jsp

I have a .jsp file and a Controller (.java file) to upload an excel file. I have an another java code to read an excel file. Both the codes are working fine independently. My question is how do I connect those two codes so that excel reading code should execute directly after uploading the file.

public class FileUploadController  {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static String UPLOAD_LOCATION="C:\\Users\\saurabh\\Desktop\\Uploads";
String fileName;
@Autowired
ServletContext context;

@Autowired
FileValidator fileValidator;

@Autowired
MultiFileValidator multiFileValidator;

@InitBinder("fileBucket")
protected void initBinderFileBucket(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(fileValidator);
}

@InitBinder("multiFileBucket")
protected void initBinderMultiFileBucket(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(multiFileValidator);
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHomePage(ModelMap model) {

    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/singleUpload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSingleUploadPage(ModelMap model) {
    FileBucket fileModel = new FileBucket();
    model.addAttribute("fileBucket", fileModel);
    return "singleFileUploader";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/singleUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String singleFileUpload(@Valid FileBucket fileBucket, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, HttpSession session) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("validation errors");
        return "singleFileUploader";
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fetching file");
        MultipartFile multipartFile = fileBucket.getFile();
        fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        fileName = new File(fileBucket.getFile().getOriginalFilename()).getName();
        String filepath = UPLOAD_LOCATION + File.separator + fileName;
        FileCopyUtils.copy(fileBucket.getFile().getBytes(), new File(filepath));
        model.addAttribute("fileName", fileName);
        //InputStream inputStream= new ByteArrayInputStream(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
        ExcelToDatabase ed = new ExcelToDatabase();
        ed.InsertNaic();
        return "success";
        //return fileName;
    }
}
```

public class ExcelReader {

```
    //InputStream inputStream1= new ByteArrayInputStream(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
    String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\saurabh\\Desktop\\Uploads\\XYZ.xlsx";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    ArrayList<String> TitleDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ContactDetails = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Codes = new ArrayList<String>();
    //ArrayList<String> CompanyName = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ExcelReader() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    }

    public List<TitleDate> TitleDate()   
    {
        List<TitleDate> list1 = new ArrayList<TitleDate>();
        for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
            XSSFRow firstRow = sheet.getRow(i);

            if(firstRow !=null) {
                for(int j= 0; j < sheet.getRow(i).getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                    String cellContactDetails = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j));
                        TitleDate.add(cellContactDetails);
                    }continue;

                }continue;
        }


        TitleDate d1 = new TitleDate();

        d1.setState(TitleDate.get(0));
        d1.setTitle(TitleDate.get(11));
        d1.setDate(TitleDate.get(33));
        d1.setNaicCode(TitleDate.get(48));
        d1.setGname(TitleDate.get(51));

        list1.add(d1);
        return list1;
    }

    public List<ContactPerson> ContactPerson()
    {

        List<ContactPerson> list=new ArrayList<ContactPerson>();

        for (int i=8; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() + 1; i++) 
        {

            XSSFRow firstRow = sheet.getRow(i);
            if(firstRow !=null) {

                    for(int j = 8; j<10; j++) {


                                String cellContactDetails = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j));
                                ContactDetails.add(cellContactDetails);

                                              }

                                }

       }

     ContactPerson c1 = new ContactPerson();

     c1.setName(ContactDetails.get(27));
     c1.setPosition(ContactDetails.get(29));
     c1.setTelephone(ContactDetails.get(31));
     c1.setEmail(ContactDetails.get(33));

     list.add(c1);
     return list;

    }
    }
```

public class ExcelToDatabase {

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/naic@data";

static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "root";


public void InsertNaic() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

Connection conn = null;
//Statement stmt = null;

try{

    String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\saurabh\\Desktop\\Uploads\\XYZ.xlsx";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

    //connecting to database
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database..");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    System.out.println("Connected to Database successfully");
    int pid = 0;
    conn.setAutoCommit(false); 
    //stmt = conn.createStatement();
    java.sql.PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    //conn.commit();
    Statement s2 = conn.createStatement();
    s2.executeQuery("SELECT (MAX(PID) + 1) FROM instructions");
    //pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    //pstm.executeQuery();
    ResultSet rs =s2.getResultSet();
    if(rs.next()) {
        pid = rs.getInt(1);
    }

    ExcelReader er = new ExcelReader();
    List<TitleDate> list1 = er.TitleDate();

    for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++) {

        TitleDate t1 = list1.get(i);    

        String state = t1.getState();
        String title = t1.getTitle();
        String date = t1.getDate();
        String code = t1.getNaicCode();
        String gname = t1.getGname();   

         for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++) {

                ContactPerson c2=list.get(j);
                String name = c2.getName();
                String c_title = c2.getPosition();
                String c_telephone = c2.getTelephone();
                String c_mail = c2.getEmail();

                    String sql1= "INSERT INTO instructions" + "(pid, state, title, Date, NAIC_CODE, Group_name, cont_name, cont_title, cont_telephone,  cont_email)" +  "VALUES ('"+ pid +"', '"+ state +"', '" + title +"', '" + date +"', '" + code +"', '"+gname  +"','" + name +"', '" + c_title + "','" + c_telephone +"', '" + c_mail +"' )"; 
                    pstm =conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
                    pstm.execute(); 
    }
    }

    System.out.println("Successfully inserted values into Instructions Table");
```

}

Comment: I think you're going to need a `ExcelFromDatabase` to fetch a file from your database (assuming `ExcelToDatabase` writes the excel to a database, and **not** a file). Of course, it looks like you have a file at `filepath` - so maybe pass that to your reader. Oh wait, your reader reads from a hardcoded file. Perhaps you should write your file there.

Comment: Yeah..that's what I was thinking how to pass the "fileName" to ExcelReader and ExcelToDatabase class.Because I don't want to store the file anywhere. Anyways, Will try your suggestion..thanks!